# Token Autthrozation Errror In login

Tags: reactjs, node.js

```js
const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.headers.authorization) {
      const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
      if (token) {
        const jwtkey = "cd9270cce63517ac6beb9681f17fb16c80dae704dd0c21c27268b3bbfcdd20e3";

        try {
          const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, jwtkey);
        

          next();
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Token verification error:', error); 
          return res.status(401).json({
            status: 401,
            message: 'Invalid Token',
          });
        }
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({
          status: 400,
          message: 'Token is missing',
        });
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: 400,
        message: 'Authorization header is missing',
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Token verification failed', error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      status: 500,
      message: 'Internal server error',
    });
  }
 
 
};
```

in this code when token verify when user login login user id but data show in admin id in and token are genrated admin id data show and login user id and user id data show and